# How to find the greatest value in a column when x is in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a lot of songs and contains columns such as 'title', 'duration' 'artists', etc. I want to find the song where 'Adele' is in 'artist' with the longest 'duration'. The thing I am specifically struggling with is separating the 'artist', as these are separated with comma separated values. So I need to check whether 'Adele' is in the list of artists, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet that creates a minimal version of the data frame you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to tell without seeing your dataframe, but if `Adele` is a string in one column and you want the max of another, you can try:

```
df[df['Artist'].str.contains('Adele')]['duration'].max()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.contains` to filter the artist. Then, `idxmax` to find the row with longest duration:

```
idx = df.loc[df['artist'].str.contains('Adele'), 'duration'].idxmax()

song_name = df.loc[idx, 'title']
```